# How can two particles be following the same geodesic path at the same instant? Why is it possible?

Tags: general-relativity

Parallel-transport is the method for measuring if a world line in spacetime is a geodesic, but how can two vectors be following that same path at the same instant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we consider motion along a geodesic we are normally considering hypothetical test particles. Any real particle will have a mass greater than zero and will change the geometry in its vicinity.

The test particles are assumed to be so small that their interactions can be  ignored, so there is no problem is placing two test particles arbitrarily close to each other. This wouldn't be true for real particles, but then for real particles the calculation would be a great deal more complicated since the geometry would be affected by the mass of the article.